# Matlab: I want to emulate a hashmap of 3D points to a list of 3D points. What is the best way?

Tags: matlab, hashmap

basically, I want to do

```
(.1,.2,.3) => ( (.1,.2,.2),(.1,.2,.1) )
(.2,.1,.1) => ( (.1,.1,.1) )
```

how would I implement this in matlab?

In java it would be a `Hashmap<3DPoint, ArrayList<3DPoint>>`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this:

You can create a `nKeys`-by-2 cell array, such as

```
{[.1,.2,.3], [.1,.2,.2;.1,.2,.1];...
[.2,.1,.1], [.1,.1,.1]}
```

While a cell array can be convenient to manipulate using e.g. [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html), it does not provide fast lookup.

If you have a more recent version of Matlab, you can use the [MAP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brqqo5e-1.html)-class. Here, numerical keys can only be scalars, but using [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html), you can convert the 3D vectors into 1-by-N strings. Make sure you write '0.1' instead of '.1', though, to avoid confusion.

Comment: how would I add a new key-value pair, or append to the value of a given key?

Comment: @DerNalia: The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brqqo5e-1.html#brq4amm-4) explains all in much more detail than I can provide here.